# How to create button with custom (different) height and width border - CSS

Tags: html, css

I would like to create a button with 100px and 100px height and with border-width 90px height 120px. But when i tried to put it it gets a strange behavior.
Is that posible?

Here an image of the style that i want to accomplish:
[image]

Comment: What have you tried so far? What is the result?
It is possible, but you need to specify your question. For now it is a "bad question" and is likely being downvoted.

Answer (score 1):

You can create `button` and add `:after` pseudo-element to create border.

```js
$('button').click(function() {
  alert('Works')
})
```

```css
body {
  background: gray;
}
button {
  padding: 10px 30px;
  background: #F26522;
  font-size: 30px;
  color: white;
  position: relative;
  border: none;
  margin: 50px;
}
button:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  height: calc(100% + 10px);
  width: calc(100% - 20px);
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  transform: translate(6px, -9px);
  border: 4px dotted white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>BUTTON</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be done using a `div` and a pseudo element like `:after` for the border part.

```css
body {
  background-color: black;
}

div {
  width: 130px;
  height: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 50px;
  background-color: #ff4f00;
  color: #fff;
  position: relative;
  margin-top: 20px;
}

div:after {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  width: 110px;
  left: 10px;
  top: -11px;
  height: 70px;
  border: 2px dotted #fff;
}
```

```html
<div>
  CONOCENOS
</div>
```